# SQL query to select a string value in the password column?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have two column **username** and **password** in **USERS** Table.
How can I get the value in **username** and **password** and compare it with another value in the program.

This is what I got. But, eclipse gives me an error:

```
String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM USERS WHERE username = ?";
```

**ERROR**:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: How do I get them more secure in the database?

Comment: im guessing that you need to put single quotes before and after the ?. like this "SELECT username, password FROM USERS WHERE username = '?' "

Comment: Use a salt and hash to get them more secure. That's one way, at least. For the original question, can we see the code that is calling the SQL statement?

Comment: you can use encryptions like md5.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/

Comment: Even better, use hashing.

Comment: @Weddy: MD5 is not secure; do not use it.  Hashing != encryption; you should not encrypt passwords.

Comment: yes thank you. noted mr. @SLaks. i was just reading about hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either prepare you sql statement and bind a parameter `?` or construct sql with actual value of `username` before executing query.

The former is the way to go to avoid sql-injection.